# Gradle task check if property is defined

Tags: gradle, properties, testng, build.gradle, task

I have a Gradle task that executes a TestNG test suite.
I want to be able to pass a flag to the task in order to use a special TestNG XML suite file (or just use the default suite if the flag isn't set).

```bash
gradle test
```

... should run the default standard suite of tests

```bash
gradle test -Pspecial
```

... should run the special suite of tests

I've been trying something like this:

```
test {
    if (special) {
        test(testng_special.xml);
    }
    else {
        test(testng_default.xml);
    }
}
```

But I get a undefined property error. What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
if (project.hasProperty('special'))
```

should do it.

Note that what you're doing to select a testng suite won't work, AFAIK: the test task doesn't have any `test()` method. Refer to https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-run-acceptance-tests-with-testng-from-gradle/4107 for a working example:

```
test {
    useTestNG {
        suites 'src/main/resources/testng.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2506293, that's not necessarily enough. You need to both check if project has a property and if **it's set**.

Comment: This is groovy @Opal - a null results in false, so you don't need to explicitly check that.

Comment: @th3morg
Thats wrong, if a property exists but is null, hasProperty(..) will still return true, so you have to use `if (project.hasProperty('special') && project.special)` if you want to check for both existance and not null.

Comment: I like to use: `project.properties["special"] == "true"`

Answer (score 6):

Here are 3 solutions for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
val prop = project.properties["myPropName"] ?: "myDefaultValue"
```

```kotlin
val prop = project.properties["myPropName"] ?: error("Property not found")
```

```kotlin
if (project.hasProperty("special")) {
    val prop = project.properties["myPropName"]
}
```

Note that you can omit the `project.` prefix as it is implicit in Gradle build files.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
test {
    if (properties.containsKey('special')) {
        test(testng_special.xml);
    }
    else {
        test(testng_default.xml);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html):

> -P, --project-prop
>
> Sets a project property of the root project, for example -Pmyprop=myvalue

So you should use:

```
gradle test -Pspecial=true
```

with a value after the property name

Comment: using JB Nizet's solution it's not necessary to set the property to true, just to define it

Comment: That's true, because you aren't reading the property value, but just checking if the property exist. Suppose that you were doing the opposite, so instead of `Special` you were using `notSpecial` and you needed a false value for this property in your condition. 
Using my solution you will not have problems because you will pass `-PnotSpecial=false` using JBNizet's solution instead the value passed was true anyway because the `notSpecial` property exist.