# How can I check gradle for property `applicationVariants`?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45101309)

> Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

I am trying to check for this property and do something *if* I have it. I assumed I could follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302279):

```
// for application modules
if (project.hasProperty('applicationVariants')) {
    println "has applicationVariants"
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       // ... do something
    }
}

// for library modules
if (project.hasProperty('libraryVariants')) {
    println "has libraryVariants"
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

However I'm not seeing any of the print statements and none of the inner code is executing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

these are properties of `project.android` - and within task `afterEvaluate` they have a value.

```
task afterEvaluate {

    if(project.android.hasProperty('applicationVariants')) {
        println("*** has applicationVariants")
    }

    if(project.android.hasProperty('libraryVariants')) {
        println("*** has libraryVariants")
    }
}
```