# How to pass command line argument to Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Here's an example from Groovy that represents exactly what I would like to achieve:

`Command line`:

```
./gradlew jib -PmyArg=hello
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
task myTask {
    doFirst {
       println myArg
       ... do what you want
    }
}
```

Source of this example is [here - option 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410854/how-to-pass-parameters-or-arguments-into-a-gradle-task/48370451#48370451).

How can I read pass and read `myArg` value in Kotlin DSL ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some time found an answer:

`build.gradle.kts`

```
val myArg: String by project // Command line argument is always a part of project

task("myTask") {
    doFirst {
        if (project.hasProperty("myArg")) {
            println(myArg)
        }
    }
}
```

`Command line`:

```
gradle myTask -PmyArg=foo
```

`Output`:

```
$ gradle myTask -PmyArg=foo

> Task :myTask
foo

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Related links:

- [How to pass arguments from command line to gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696629/2009145)
- [How to pass parameters or arguments into a gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410854/how-to-pass-parameters-or-arguments-into-a-gradle-task/48370451#48370451])
- [Gradle task check if property is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302279/2009145)

Comment: That doesn't work (for me), since variable `myArg` is undefined at compile time of build.gradle.kts. It works with `project.properties["myArg"]`.

Answer (score 6):

I retrieved the argument for my task like this (build.gradle.kts with [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)):

```kotlin
tasks.create("myCustomTask") {
  doLast {
    val myArg = properties["myArgName"]
    // OR a more verbose form:
    val myArg = project.properties["myArgName"]
  }
}
```

```sh
./gradlew myCustomTask -PmyArgName=hello
```