# Translate 'project.hasProperty()' in 'settings.gradle' from groovy to kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy

I am trying to translate all groovy-scripts in a gradle project to kotlin. The only problem I currently still have is translating the file `settings.gradle` in the root directory of my project. In the groovy-script there is an if-condition `if(project.hasProperty("someProperty"))`. Unfortunately, when trying to translate it to kotlin, the `project` keyword is not recognized anymore. Furthermore, in the same folder I have a `build.gradle.kts`, which is written in kotlin and in which I can use the `project`keyword in an if-condition as described before without any problem. It just doesn't seem to work, when I want to translate the groovy-script in `settings.gradle` to kotlin in `settings.gradle.kts`.

The project is a gradle project and the `settings.gradle` looks as follows:

```
include ':subproject-a',
        ':subproject-b'

if (project.hasProperty("someProperty")) {
    include ':subproject-c'
}
```

I would like to translate this to kotlin like so:

```
include(":subproject-a",
        ":subproject-b")

if (project.hasProperty("someProperty")) {
    include(":subproject-c")
}
```

However, when I do that, `project` is not recognized. Even though, as mentioned before, it worked just like that in `build.gradle.kts` (which is written in kotlin, translated from groovy), which is in the same folder.

Comment: Have you tried `rootProject` instead of `project`?

Comment: What you have I do not think works or has ever worked.

According to the documentation for `Settings` instance: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html

There is no such property or method named `project`.

Comment: or you can access your property by involving reflection workaround like [this](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/635#issue-283219430) or you can use `val myVar: String by project` delegation as stated [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/commit/4e8a53b47c81af2996efdfecceb6a18b83ee65d5) & [here for stackoverflow answer in details (recommended to read)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56535952/3763032)